# HOW TO: Class functions pointers (C++)

Tags: c++, class, function-pointers

I have some problems with understanding function pointers. Although I've read lots of topics on this I still have problems with the follow case.

My example is simple - I have a joystick class which has some function pointers as well as functions through which these pointers can be assigned and I don't know how to do this properly.

I'll try to keep it simple:

```
class Joystick {
    void (Player::*OnShootKeyPressed)();  // pointer that takes no arguments and returns nothing

    void SetCallback(void (Player::*f)) {
       OnShotKeyPressed = f;
    }
}

class Player {
   void OnShootAction() { ...do the shooting...}

   void Initialize() {
      Joystick* joy = pInputMng->GetJoystick();

      joy->SetCallback( &Player::OnShootAction() );
   }
}
```

*--Edited after Captain Obvlious comment--*

That's one short example of what I want to achieve and I don't seem to understand these function pointers correctly. What am I doing wrong?

I appreciate all the help in advance!

Comment: You can't pass a pointer to member function as a pointer to a function, they are not the same thing. FWIW the syntax is `&Player::OnShootAction` not `&OnShootAction()`.

Comment: Stroll through this https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/pointers-to-members .

Comment: Thanks @CaptainObvlious but I still can't make it work.

Comment: @user4581301 - I did and if I got everything right that page says I shouldn't do that...

Comment: What specific error message is giving you trouble?

Comment: One thing to watch out for is `Joystick` has no clue which `Player`s `OnShotKeyPressed` is being called. Don't know the player, can't provide the hidden `this` parameter. Take a look into [std::bind](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind). It might be an easier solution.

Comment: Also: Some extremely valuable, practical comments regarding using this stuff here: https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/pointers-to-members#typedef-for-ptr-to-memfn Edit: oops just realized user4581301 already linked that. Seriously though, what are you having trouble with that is not covered there

Comment: BloodyAvenger: seriously, try using a typedef for the member function pointers in your code instead, it will most likely work or give a very clear error message.

Comment: Hey, thanks to everyone for all the effort and sorry for taking this long to reply. I was having following problems.

1. I'm using namespaces and compiler required to state namespace but when I stated namespace it said it's not recognized...I solved this though. That was the MAIN issue.

2. Calling a Function pointer requires a reference to an object:  
(Player->*OnShootAction)();  ... I didn't know that as well.

I'll use typdefs like you suggested @ChrisBeck, thanks.

I found out I have a small problem in my code structure but now I know how to make it right.

Thanks again everyone! :)

Comment: Please don't edit a solution into the question. Instead, accept a posted answer. If there are no good answers posted you may write one yourself and accept it.

Comment: Thanks for warning me about that. It's indeed a better way, thanks @MattMcNabb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**CORRECTED CODE & ANSWER**

**1.)** I was having some problems with namespaces not mentioned in the question so I wasn't able to create a function.

Both classes were under the namespace so the function for assigning a function pointer was rejected:

```
void                        SetCallback(void (ehJoystick::*f)())
```

It was required to be this instead:

```
void                        SetCallback(void (eg::ehJoystick::*f)())
```

But then, compiler didn't accept the namespace infront of that. I thought I was doing something wrong elsewhere but there problem was there all the time.

**2.)** I didn't know you need an object reference where you want to call a member function pointer. Following code is correct and working.

```
class Joystick {
    Player* pPlayer;
    void (Player::*OnShootKeyPressed)() = NULL;  // pointer that takes no arguments and returns nothing

    void SetCallback(void (Player::*f)(), Player *p) {
        OnShotKeyPressed = f;
        pPlayer = p; // we need a reference to the object
    }
    void OnKeyPressed(key) {
        if( key == SHOOT && OnShootKeyPressed != NULL ) {
            (pPlayer->*OnShootKeyPressed)(); //that's how the function is called
        }
    }

class Player {
    void OnShootAction() { ...do the shooting...}

    void Initialize() {
    Joystick* joy = pInputMng->GetJoystick();

    joy->SetCallback( &Player::OnShootAction, this );
}
```

Comment: `&Player::OnShootAction()` isn't valid, it should be `&Player::OnShootAction`

Comment: You'll also need to predeclare `class Player;` before your `class Joystick { ... }` definition if you haven't done so already

Comment: Thanks for correction and yes, Player class needs to be Predeclared.

Comment: Now that Joystick knows player, you have obsoleted the need for a method pointer. If you implement the `OnKeyPressed` method beneath  the definition of `Player`, `OnKeyPressed` can call any public `Player` methods.

Comment: @user4581301 They might want to make it so that keys are rebindable to different functions. If they take it a little further they can abstract the buttons from the Joystick into a generic controller and have it so that they can bind keyboard and mouse buttons to player actions as well. They'll end up with a highly extensible and user customisable system which allows for multiple players on one machine.

Answer (score 1):

I love function pointers. I consider them among my best personal friends. But this is probably not the time for them. When you have whole objects calling each other back and forth, Just pass the object.

If you need greater decoupling between the objects, build an interface. I'll go with the interface route because why not? Once you've seen the hard way, the easy way's easy.

First, define an interface for users of the joystick

```
class ButtonUser
{
    virtual void OnShootAction() = 0; // function to be implemented by children
    virtual void OnJumpAction() = 0; 
    virtual void OnDeathBlossomAction() = 0; 
    ...
}
```

Now a joystick that uses the button interface and knows absolutely nothing about Player

```
class Joystick {
    ButtonUser * pUser;

    void SetCallback(ButtonUser * puser) {
        pUser = puser;
    }
    void OnKeyPressed(key) {
        if (pUser != NULL) {
            switch( key ) {
                 case SHOOT: 
                     pUser->OnShootAction(); 
                     break;
                 case JUMP: 
                     pUser->OnjumpAction(); 
                     break;
                 case DB: 
                     pUser->OnDeathBlossomAction(); 
                     break;
                 ...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And Player installs itself as Joystick's user

```
class Player: public ButtonUser{
    void OnShootAction() { ...do the shooting...}
    void OnJumpAction() {...jump...}; 
    void OnDeathBlossomAction() {...blow $#!+ up!...}
    ...

    void Initialize() {
    Joystick* joy = pInputMng->GetJoystick();

    joy->SetCallback( this );
}
```

Comment: That's actually a really good solution and even much cleaner. I'll replace my function pointers code to this now. Cheers!